Quesiton regarding nature of equations involving fractional part and greatest integer functions
This question is in context of the following problem
Solve: $[x]^2 = x + 2\{x\}$ Where $[.]$ and $\{.\}$ represent the greatest integer and fractional part function respectively.
The solution for the above question in my textbook is given as follows
$$[x]^2 = x + 2\{x\}$$
$$[x]^2 = [x] + 3\{x\}$$
$$\{x\} = \frac{[x]^2 - [x]}{3}$$
$$0 \leq \frac{[x]^2 - [x]}{3} < 1$$
$$0 \leq [x]^2 - [x] < 3$$
$$[x] \in (\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}, 0] \cup [1, \frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2})$$
Then this question is basically solved taking values of $[x]$ and then finding the values of $x$.
The main issue i have is how do we get range of values of $[x]$, i notice that $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}$ are the roots of $x^2 - x - 3$ which can be formed in the above equation by moving the 3 around and replacing x with $[x]$.
But i do not understand how this helps.
Could someone please point me in the right direction.
Any help would be appreciated!

This is often known as the wavy curve method, or the method of intervals. For a quadratic, this is rather easy. Note that the function $f(x) = x^2 - x - 3$ will be a parabola with its open end facing up (i.e., bounded from below, unbounded from above). It cuts the $x$ axis at its two roots, and is below the x axis between those two values, and above it outside that interval.

As a general rule, if $f(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial with a positive leading coefficient, with roots $x_1,x_2$, then $f(x)$ is negative iff $x$ lies in $(x_1,x_2)$

Imagine your polynomial to be in the form of $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)$$
Where $a_n=n^{th}$root of the polynomial.
Now for the sake of making it easy for understanding, let the factors be arranged such that $a_1>a_2>a_3>...>a_n$
Now try to visualise
For $x>a_1\implies (x-a_1)>0$
But as $a_1>a_2>a_3>...>a_n$,
$$ 0<(x-a_1)<(x-a_2)<(x-a_3)...<(x-a_n)$$
Hence $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)>0 \forall x \in (a_1,∞)$$
For $a_1>x>a_2$:-
Here the value of $(x-a_1)$ becomes negative. But all other values concerning $a_2,a_3...$ are still positive. As one value in the product is negative, the entire product must be negative
Hence $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)<0 \forall x \in (a_2,a_1)$$
For $a_2>x>a_3$:-
Here the values of both $(x-a_1)$and $(x-a_2)$ become negative, while all other values like $(x-a_3),(x-a_4)$ remain postive. But as there are even number of negative values, their product yields a positive value. Thus
$$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)>0 \forall x \in (a_3,a_2)$$
This pattern repeats for all $a_n$, with their product alternating signs for each interval.
There is a breach in this system if a certain factor is repeated even times. Say the inequality was $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)^2(x-a_3)..(x-a_n)>0 \forall x \in (a_1,∞)$$
Then for both $a_1>x>a_2$ and $a_2>x>a_3$ , the value of the product will stay negative, as here the only negative value is $(x-a_1)$, and $(x-a_2)^2$ will always be positive.
What I explained is known as the wavy curve method or method of intervals.
Now for your question, simply substitute {$x$} with $y$, and break your inequality in two parts.
$$0≤y^2 - y \implies 0≤y(y-1) $$ Using our concept of intervals, we can say that this value is positive  or 0 if $1≤y$ or $y≤0$. So $y \in [1,∞) \cup (-∞,0]$. Now for the other part
$$y^2-y-3<0 \implies (y-\frac{1+\sqrt {13}}{2})(y-\frac{1-\sqrt {13}}{2})<0$$
Hence we can say $y \in (\frac{1-\sqrt {13}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt {13}}{2})$.
For the final answer, we need to take values which suffice both intervals.
Thus $y \in (\frac{1-\sqrt {13}}{2},0] \cup [1,\frac{1+\sqrt {13}}{2})$.
